How does the dynamic linker resolve symbols at run time?
I'm trying to understand how the dynamic linker resolves symbols at run time. I read chunks (but not all) of David Beazley et. al's The Inside Story on Shared Libraries and Dynamic Loading, but I don't completely understand how data references are resolved. I may have missed the relevant parts though.
I see how the indirection introduced by the PLT helps patch the CALL instruction, because CALL followed by JMP is essentially CALL from the caller's perspective. But how about data references? Imagine an assignment such as x = 5. The compiler will essentially compile this to some sort of MOVE involving the address of x (sooner or later). I can understand how this address is patched (directly) when multiple .o's are combined to build an executable, but don't we need indirection in this case too? How does patching look for an instruction like MOV, something that is not a CALL?
Are all the PLT's of all the shared libraries combined to one giant PLT at run-time and all CALL addresses patched to address in this PLT? Does the same happen for .data and .bss? I know that happens when combining multiple .o's, but what about the case of shared libraries at run-time? How can a single copy of the shared library be shared across processes, because the same symbol could resolve differently in different contexts?
Please feel free to point me to other sources for reading.

Read https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/11/03/position-independent-code-pic-in-shared-libraries/ and https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/08/25/load-time-relocation-of-shared-libraries/
